# How can I resolve a ParametrizedType / TypeVariable when I know the ParametrizedType of the class it's in?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am using reflection proxies to perform additional checking on a public API. Essentially I want to wrap every object that comes back from it so that any object the caller gets their hands on is a proxy to the real object.

Java still has the whole erasure problem, so I am passing the type of the wrapped object around with it. I should know what type everything is because the entry into the API is a single, non-generic interface.

```
public class ProxyInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private final Object delegate;
    private final Type delegateType;

    public ProxyInvocationHandler(Object delegate, Type delegateType) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.delegateType = delegateType;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) {
        // Omitted: additional checks performed here.

        Object result = method.invoke(delegate, args);

        Type returnType = method.getGenericReturnType();

        // e.g. if delegateType is List<Cat> and the method is the get method,
        // returnType would be E but resultType should be Cat.
        Type resultType = ???

        // Utility method I will omit, it just creates another proxy instance
        // using its own invocation handler.
        return ProxyUtils.wrap(result, resultType);
    }
}
```

I have looked around the Type / ParametrizedType API and can't seem to find a way to get `resultType`, even though `delegateType` and `returnType` should be enough information to compute this.

What is the "proper" way to do this?

Comment: whats the difference between "resultType" and "returnType"?

Comment: resultType is the actual type of result. returnType is the return type as declared by the method signature. e.g. if delegateType is List<Cat> and the method is the get method, returnType would be E but resultType would be Cat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Java ClassMate](https://github.com/cowtowncoder/java-classmate) for that purpose. You'll have to use `com.fasterxml.classmate.GenericType` for type tokens:

```
GenericType<?> delegateType = new GenericType<List<Cat>>() {};
```

Note the empty `{}` that's called the ["Super-type Token" pattern](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html).

```
TypeResolver typeResolver = new TypeResolver();
MemberResolver memberResolver = new MemberResolver(

ResolvedType type = typeResolver.resolve(delegateType);
ResolvedTypeWithMembers members = memberResolver.resolve(type, null, null);
ResolvedMethod[] methods = members.getMemberMethods();
```

Cache the results in a `Map`:

```
Map<Method, ResolvedMethod> resolved = new HashMap<>();
for (ResolvedMethod method: methods) {
    resolved.put(method.getRawMember(), method);
}
```

Now, when you have a method declared by the `delegateType`, i.e. `List`, you can get its *resolved* return type:

```
Method method = List.class.getMethod("get", int.class);
ResolvedType resultType = resolved.get(method).getReturnType();
System.out.println("resultType = " + resultType);              // prints resultType = Cat
```

Comment: I feared a library might be involved. I think Guava has something along these lines too. If it doesn't, I'll use FasterXML's - they tend to make good stuff. :)

Comment: @Trejkaz Can you please post whatever you find here? I want to know if a more elegant library has the same functionality.

Comment: Done. Posted as an alternative answer. It's really very simple, but instead of GenericType it's TypeToken, and I maybe avoided a few lines of code because ClassMate separate the resolver into a separate utility whereas Guava put it directly onto TypeToken itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Guava way, for people who come by in the future:

```
...
Type returnType = method.getGenericReturnType();
TypeToken<?> resultType = TypeToken.of(delegateType).resolveType(returnType);
```

I changed the type of delegateType to `TypeToken<?>` to make things a little easier. And of course, I added quite a bit of caching (using a `LoadingCache`) to get the performance down to a sensible speed. Their resolution code was slower than my initial hacked-up code which did the same thing. The difference is that I now have the confidence that it's being done correctly.

Comment: Very nice. I may need to switch to Guava myself :)